# Conformal Cosmology Confusion

Tags: cosmology, photons, space-expansion, conformal-field-theory

When we look into the far future of the universe, it seems possible that it might reach a state where photons are basically all that remains.

Roger Penrose states that the universe would ‘forget’ its size and age at that point. I can follow that thinking.

Then he says though, that the photons will hit a boundary, creating cause for a new aeon.

I don’t understand what boundary they will hit?

Does he mean that expansion will have ceased by that point, creating a boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good answer but until a better one comes along...

I'll assume you're referring to [Penrose's original presentation](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/e06/PAPERS/THESPA01.PDF). I don't see anything there about *hitting* a boundary. Spacetime does *have* a conformal boundary, which Penrose is famous for illustrating in what are now called [Penrose diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_diagram) (or Penrose-Carter diagrams). All that Penrose seems to argue is that it's possible in principle to identify the past and future boundaries of a ΛCDM-like cosmology: i.e., there's nothing mathematically forbidden about it as long as physics is truly conformal there.

Aside from the problem of there being no justification for doing it, it also seems like a problem that the boundaries are defined as times where the scale factor goes to $0$ or $\infty$, and if the scale factor is to be ignored then there's no longer any reason to put the boundaries at any particular time. To put it another way, after the universe forgets its size, it's not clear why it would suddenly remember a different, smaller size and trigger a big bang at any particular conformal time, or at all.

So I think the problem of "creating cause for a new aeon" is real and Penrose has no solution to it. However it's not clear to me that CCC is any worse off than inflation or other proposals in that regard.

Comment: Many thanks. To me, it’s a useful answer indeed. Perhaps the term ‘hitting’ is just Penrose’s way of describing it. I’ve seen him hit one hand off the other in talks - implying an impetus against a ‘solid’ boundary, but as you explain, there ain’t one.

Comment: I’m just wondering if, since all the photons will theoretically reach infinity instantaneously, would that be the inferred ‘new Big Bang?’ 

So, the entire energy present in our universe now will be conserved in the photon-only state of the distant future?

Comment: Animistic descriptions, like descriptions of particles as "living" on a surface, generally give me a pain, but, if one considers the way memory works--not providing a script continuously running a certain temporal distance behind one's present, but, rather, providing a script that one can look at now and again--Penrose's analogy might be a good one, and his cosmological model does have the great advantage (over, say, field-based inflation) that it doesn't require a beginning:  Beginnings go well beyond animism in the realm of magical thinking.